# Invariant subspace for a given operator

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

I have studied that given an operator f  that can be either a symmetric, or a skew-symmetric, or an orthogonal operator
in a Euclidean space $V$ and $U ⊂ V$ be its invariant subspace. Then $U^⊥$ is also an invariant for f.

But I came across a question that asks to provide a counterexample for this i.e. give an example of an operator f on some Euclidean (or Hermitian) vector space
such that it has an invariant subspace $U$ and $f(U^⊥)$ does not belong to $U^⊥$

I do not understand this we proved that given any general operator it will have an invariant subspace and we are asking to provide a counterexample to that. It's confusing.

Comment: You didn't show it held for general operators $f$, per your first paragraph -- but just symmetric, skew-symmetric, or orthogonal ones. So find an operator $f$ that is none of these, and that'll be a starting point.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer if A be a symmetric operator. Let x ∈ U, y ∈ $U^⊥$, then (x, Ay) = (Ax, y) = 0, since Ax ∈ U, y ∈ $U^⊥$. The same works for a skew-symmetric operator.
Suppose A is orthogonal. Then A |U also is orthogonal and non-degenerate. Let y ∈ $U^⊥$
and x ∈ U. We need Ay ∈ $U^⊥$, i.e. (x, Ay) = 0. But since A |U is non-degenerate, then there exists z ∈ U, such that x = Az. Then (x, Ay) = (Az, Ay) = (z, y) = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Define $T: \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{2}$ by $T(x,y)=(x+y,0)$. Verify that $U=\{(x,y): y=0\}$ is an invariant subspace but $U^{\perp} = \{(x,y): x=0\}$ is not invaraint.